# Will Polyurethane bond to a surface that was sanded with 320 grit?

Tags: polyurethane

I have some MDF that was sanded with a random orbital sander with 320grit

Will polyurethane make a decent bond to this?

Comment: Sure, I see no reason it wouldn't if the surface is clean and dust free.

Comment: ok.  I ask cause I keep reading that it needs to be a rough surface...120 grit... to have more surface area to bond.

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea to use such a coarse sandpaper. You can urethane on the smoothest of surfaces. As long as it is clean and dust free, it will bond fine.

Comment: thanks!  hard to know what you're reading is the truth or not sometimes -_-

Comment: be sure to sand between coats of urethane with super fine paper, 220 or finer for a nice smooth finish. Be sure to remove all dust before putting on the next coat.